# How to get the roles of user who messaged in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm kind of new to this, but I have this

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const auth = require("./auth.json");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
    console.log(msg.guild.roles.get);
    if (msg.content === 'ping') {
        msg.reply('Pong!');
    }
});

client.login(auth.token);
```

But when it console.logs it, I get `undefined`. How can I get the roles of the user who just messaged. I looked at all the examples online and it feels like they are on an older API where the `.get` method works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to refer to examples online. Just read the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/) - the developers spent lots of effort writing it to answer these exact questions efficiently.

You're looking for "the roles of the user who just messaged". You can get the user who just messaged by the `msg.author` or `msg.member` properties. Not knowing any better, you could simply [check the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) on both of these properties to see what you can get out of them. In this case, you want a user's guild-specific data, so you want their `GuildMember` object for this guild - that's `msg.member`.

Looking at the [docs for `GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) you can observe all the properties you can access. There is a `roles` property right there, which is of type [`GuildMemberRoleManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager). That type has a `.cache` property which contains your Collection of cached roles.

Putting it all together you get this: `msg.member.roles.cache`. This is a collection so you can iterate over it any way supported by collections (`for..of`, `.forEach()`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const auth = require("./auth.json");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
    for(var role of msg.member.roles.cache) {
        console.log("id:", role[0], "name:", role[1].name);
    }
    if (msg.content === 'ping') {
        msg.reply('Pong!');
    }
});

client.login(auth.token);
```